# Display the last part of URL javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to display the last part of a URL using javascript!

I am using this code but this will display the entire URL:

```
<script language="javascript">

document.writeln(document.location);
var url = $(this).attr("href");
var part = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

</script>
```

if the URL look like this:

domain.com/something/file

i need to only display the "file".

Comment: You might be doing the right thing; but I think it's only writing "document.location", in that first line. Try document.writeln(part) at the end.

Comment: Check my answer, with the JSFiddle :)

Comment: The use of `attr('href')` *implies* (assuming you know what you're doing) that you might be trying to get the URL from the `href` of an `a` element, rather than the page-location. But I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do. Can you explain your intent a little better?

Comment: @DavidThomas, No, i don't really know what I am doing if I'm honest. I have explained the exact same thing that I am trying to do and none of the answers helped me so far!

Comment: @DavidThomas, and yes, I am trying to get the URL from the page location.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var segment_str = window.location.pathname; // return segment1/segment2/segment3/segment4
var segment_array = segment_str.split( '/' );
var last_segment = segment_array.pop();
document.write(last_segment); // alerts segment4

</script>
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HNMV3/1/

Comment: what is this suppose to be?

Comment: Check out the JSFiddle. It does what you want. :)

Comment: I did check it out. it opens an alert and it says "safe"! what is safe?!

Comment: Safe is the last URI segment in the sample URL that I have coded in the JavaScript. The code basically does what you wanted. It lets you "display the last part of a URL" as your question here asks. I hope I get voted up and selected as the best solution for my efforts :)

Comment: also, i don't want it to be in an alert window. i need it to be displayed on the page like my own example.

Comment: oh, yeah, I got it now. :) but how can I display it on the page like my own example instead of an alert window?

Comment: It uses document.write()

Comment: Click Run after http://jsfiddle.net/HNMV3/1/ this opens.

Anyway, I have provided the code on SO , just above the link.

But try clicking run, some JSFiddle issue. It should work Simon.

Answer (score 14):

The reason `document.write(window.location)` writes the location is because of the `toString` method of `window.location`, which really returns `window.location.href`.

```
// This will fallback to the location.pathname if this
// is not the location already or not an anchor.
var path = this.pathname || window.location.pathname;
var part = path.split('/').pop();
```

Pathname is everything after the domain name. So, `http://example.com/something/file` breaks down like this:

1. protocol: `http:`
2. hostname: `example.com`
3. pathname: `something/file`
4. href: `http://example.com/something/file`

(there is also port, search (`?this=that`) and hash (`#hash`), which would both be empty in this case)

So, I'm taking `something/file` and [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)ting it into an array wherever this is a `/`, which would be `["something", "file"]`

After that I'm [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)ping off the last part of the array, in this case "file"

---

Both `window.location` and any `<a>` tag have these properties. So, if you need to parse a URL, you can do the following in javascript:

```
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.href = '/about'; // this could be any relative or absolute url
```

And now `anchor` will have the all those properties if you need them. No need for a regex or anything.

---

**UPDATE**

In newer browsers (excluding IE unless you use [url-polyfill](https://github.com/lifaon74/url-polyfill)), you can use [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) instead of an `<a />` like so:

```
const url = new URL('/about', this.location)
// or if you don't care about the host, you can do the following
// const url = new URL('http://localhost/about')
```

This contains all the other information, plus [`url.searchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams), which makes it so you don't have to parse the search string yourself either.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `this.location.pathname`? or `window.location.pathname` for more assurance?

Comment: Not if it's an anchor tag, which is what I was assuming given the context of the question. Otherwise, yes :)

Comment: any explanation would be great.

Comment: Updated with an explanation

Answer (score 1):

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname,
    part = pathname.substr(pathname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

replace(/-/g," ") and split(".html") will remove "hyphens" and ".html" from url,thus only keeping the  path name only

```
var parts=window.location.pathname.split("/");
var query=parts[parts.length-1].split(".html");
query[0]=query[0].replace(/-/g," ");
document.write(query[0])
```